# Нахватал минусов за самоответ

Tags: обсуждение, самоответы

Сам вопрос: [Каков механизм добавления элементов в ArrayList?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1060744/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-arraylist)

Вопрос я сформулировал, пытаясь покрыть выдачу гугла. Он был исключительно для аккумуляции знаний. Отправил вопрос уже с ответом. Что я сделал не так (и сделал ли)? Как улучшить свой вопрос?

Comment: На мой взгляд вопрос и ответ - нормальные, плюсы поставил. Минусы, думаю, от людей, которые не прочитали ответ и поставили минус на вопрос думая, что ТС просто поленился открыть исходник класса. Если это верно, то, наверное, улучшить вопрос можно добавлением вопросов о необходимости в ответе подробной информации о смысле кода в исходниках.

Comment: Думаю, если вопрос "задан" для того, чтобы в ответе аккумулировать собранную по нему информацию (для отсылки из часто задаваемых вопросов, просто считая наличие такого вопросо-ответ полезным и т.п.) - нет смысла стесняться, и надо явно об этом в вопросе написать. Ну нет тут отдельного раздела ака FAQ, а ты выкрутился - так почему об этом не сказать?

Comment: @Akina, метка [tag:faq] кстати есть :-) и по языкам некоторым

Comment: @Grundy Метка-то тут каким боком? её ж ещё надо догадаться в поиске указать (а для большинства вопрошающих просто догадаться поискать - уже подвиг)...

Answer (score 4):

> Как улучшить свой вопрос?

По-моему, в вопросах для самоответа стоит использовать нейтральные формулировки, избегая "ролевого" повествования от первого лица (например, *«мне непонятно»*, *«я хотел бы узнать»*, и т.д.) - последние вводят участников в заблуждение относительно мотивов вопроса/автора... И это может вызвать закономерно негативную реакцию, при появлении авторского ответа.

В твой вопрос я уже внес правку, и его смысл вроде не пострадал.
(проверь, пожалуйста)

Также, я создал [метку `[самоответ]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82/info) с описанием, и добавил ее к вопросу.
Если эта метка пройдет "экспертизу", и не будет удалена - предлагаю использовать ее в будущем.

Comment: Да, все в порядке. А про метку - это вы хорошо придумали.

Comment: не надо метку [tag:самоответ]

Comment: @Grundy, Надо. Причем, надо не только для определения характера вопроса до его прочтения, и удобного поиска таких вопросов - а еще и для комфорта тех, кто не хочет видеть подобные вопросы в списке (игнор метки).

Comment: @yar85, это метаметка, а метаметки не нужны.

Comment: @Grundy, А разве кто-то принуждает тех, кому она не нужна?

Answer (score -11):

Голос против — это плата за потраченное время на ваш вопрос.

Если человек начал уже отвечать на него, а тут бац, развёрнутый ответ от вас, что в целом намекает, мол можете не стараться, это не очень то и приятно. Поэтому, на будущее, об этом лучше предупреждать заранее.

Comment: Когда человек приходит на SO, он по идее должен понимать, что в любом случае жертвует свое время - _для **общего** блага_. А  тем, кто фармит репутацию, лучше сидеть на хабрах/лорах, во избежание душевных травм: SO все-таки не для них сделан, а для сообщества. Имхо.

Comment: @yar85 Я регулярно читаю хабр и со всей уверенностью могу заявить: люди, обитающие на хабре, карма-онанистами (ну или кармадрочерами, кому как больше нравится) считают завсегдатаев SO, а себя считают носителями белых польт (или польтов?) не хуже, чем вы себя ;)

Comment: @Dmitriy, Прошу, расскажи больше о том, что и как я считаю (из того что не написано в моих комментариях). Это очень уместная и нужная информация.

Comment: Если бы за каждый пост, на который кто-то потратил своё время или из-за которого кому-то стало неприятно минус бы ставили... я не думаю, что в таком случае SO был бы успешен. По-моему лично мнению у минусов должны быть более объективные причины.

Comment: "Голос против — это плата за потраченное время на ваш вопрос" - это не так работает.

Comment: Нет, дело в том, что ответ уже был опубликован с самоответом(по крайней мере при публикации вопроса я поставил галочку в поле самоответ и добавил его туда. Вместе с ответом и "задал")

Comment: @yar85 а вот это щас обидно было. Слова "хабр" и "лор" ставить рядом может только тот, кто ни разу не читал обсуждения на этих сайтах.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Триггериться на слова может только тот, кто игнорирует общий смысл написанного. ЛОР и хабр в комментарии ставятся рядом по четко обозначенному признаку - но при этом не утверждается что обсуждения там одинаковы или схожи (конечно же, не схожи. Речь вообще не про обсуждения).